# SKTexture from UIImage looks different

Tags: ios, uiimage, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

I'm playing around with SpriteKit and I'm creating a SKTexture from an UIImage, then using   SKSpriteNode to add the child to my SKScene (As a background), everything works fine, except that the UIImage looks very different from the original image, I tried to recreate the image in photoshop and the issue still remains, tested on Simulator and real device and different image colors, no changes.

The image format is PNG, and I added through Images.xcassets in Xcode 5

Image, results:

[image]

Different image, results:

[image]

I'm using the following code in my SKScene subclass:

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        SKTexture *textureGradient = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"]];
        SKSpriteNode* spriteGradient = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:textureGradient];
        [self addChild:spriteGradient];

    }
    return self;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: It looks vertically stretched? Double check your sizes

Comment: Is the `SKSpriteNode`'s color property set? Do you change the alpha anywhere?

Comment: Thank you guys! looks that the image was stretched. Solved with spriteGradient.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

It was my fault, the image position was wrong, so I changed the position property:

```
SKTexture *textureGradient = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"]];
SKSpriteNode* spriteGradient = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:textureGradient];
spriteGradient.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:spriteGradient];
```